# Determine whether the following is a subspace of the indicated vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

> Is $\{(x_1,x_2):x_1-5x_2=0\}$ a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$ ?

I know the zero vector is in the subspace because if $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2=0$ then it is in the subspace.

is it allowed to set $5x_1 - 5x_2 = 0$ which would prove the vector addition clause.

I guess i feel pretty lost and I'm trying to understand how to determine the subset to be able to answer the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show it is subspace, you have to show that the zero  vector (in this case, the vector = (0,0)) is in $U = \{ (x_1,x_2) : x_1 - 5x_2 = 0 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, that if you take two vectors ${\bf x} \in U$ and ${\bf x'} \in U$ then ${\bf x+x'} \in U$ and if $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\alpha {\bf x} \in U$.

Clearly, $0-5\cdot 0 = 0$ thus the vector $(0,0) \in U$.

Now, take two vectors in $U$, say ${\bf x} = (x_1,x_2)$ and ${\bf x'} = (x_1',x_2') \in U$. This means that $x_1 - 5x_2 = 0$ and $x_1' - 5x_2' = 0$

Now, I want to show that ${\bf x + x'} \in U$. In other words, I want to show that $(x_1+x_1')-5(x_2+x_2')=0$. Indeed,

\begin{align*}
(x_1+x_1')-5(x_2+x_2') &= x_1+x_1' - 5x_2-5x_2' \\
     &= (x_1-5x_2) + (x_1'-5x_2') \\
&= 0 + 0\\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Now, if $\alpha$ is a scalar, and ${\bf x} \in U$ can you show that $\alpha {\bf x}$ is in $U$? That is, you want to show that $\alpha x_1 - 5 (\alpha x_2) = 0$. Isn't it obvious?